# How to destructure tuple struct with reference

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use the hyper library to make some requests. The [`Headers::get()`](http://hyper.rs/hyper/v0.9.12/hyper/header/struct.Headers.html#method.get) method returns `Option<&H>`, where `H` is a tuple struct with one field. I can use `if let Some()` to destructure the `Option`. But how do we destructure the `&H`? Sure I could always access the field with `.0`, but I'm curious if Rust has a syntax to do this.

```
struct s(String);

fn f(input: &s) -> &s {
    input
}

fn main() {
    let my_struct1 = s("a".to_owned());
    let s(foo) = my_struct1;
    let my_struct2 = s("b".to_owned());
    let &s(bar) = f(&my_struct2); // this does not work
    let baz = &my_struct2.0; // this works
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you try to compile this, the Rust compiler will tell you how to fix the error with a nice message:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> <anon>:11:9
   |
11 |     let &s(bar) = f(&my_struct2); // this does not work
   |         ^^^---^
   |         |  |
   |         |  hint: to prevent move, use `ref bar` or `ref mut bar`
   |         cannot move out of borrowed content
```

This is needed to tell the compiler that you only want a reference to the field in the struct; the default matching will perform a move and the original struct value will no longer be valid.

Let's fix the example:

```
struct s(String);

fn f(input: &s) -> &s {
    input
}

fn main() {
    let my_struct1 = s("a".to_owned());
    let s(foo) = my_struct1;
    let my_struct2 = s("b".to_owned());
    let &s(ref bar) = f(&my_struct2);
}
```

Another way is to dereference first and drop the `&`. I think this is preferred in Rust:

```
struct s(String);

fn f(input: &s) -> &s {
    input
}

fn main() {
    let my_struct1 = s("a".to_owned());
    let s(foo) = my_struct1;
    let my_struct2 = s("b".to_owned());
    let s(ref bar) = *f(&my_struct2);
}
```

Comment: I tried `s(ref bar) = f(&my_struct2)`, but not as your answer. The combination of `&` and `ref` seems to be double referencing, which I thought is wrong.